# what is AP time zone abbreviation

Tags: time, calendar

whenever I google times in other countries I get these (that's by my local date: Solar Hijri calendar)

For example "Time in USA" :
Thursday, Shahrivar 22, 1397 **AP** (EDT)

"Time in India" : Friday, Shahrivar 23, 1397 **AP** (GMT+5:30)

and "Time in Iran" : Friday, Shahrivar 23, 1397 **AP** (GMT+4:30)

And the question is **AP** that I didn't find in time zone abbreviations listed on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations).

PS: according to here: https://24timezones.com/time-zone/gmt+4:30
, shouldn't be **IRDT**? so why google shows me **AP**?

Comment: This doesn't actually have anything to do with programming so it's off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a timezone descriptor. In this case "AP" means "Anno Persico" or "Anno Persarum", meaning "Persian year". See https://www.tondering.dk/claus/cal/persian.php, https://www.allacronyms.com/AP/Anno_Persico, or https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_calendar

Comment: Bravo! is this weird word Latin origin?

Comment: "Anno" is certainly the Latin (and Italian, come to think of it) word for "year". "Persico" commonly translates as "Persian Gulf", while "persarum" translates as "Persian", e.g. "Imperium Persarum" = "Persian Empire", i.e. the series of empires once ruled by the Achaemenid dynasty, the Seleucids, the Parthians, and the Sassanids prior to the Muslim conquests of the mid-to-late 7th century.